# Android 6.0 paste shortcut not work

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need to emulate android paste keyboard shortcut.In all android sdk everything work good, except android 6.0.

**Before android 6.0** i use menu + v, paste work
**On android 6.0** i try menu + v, ctrl + v, but it is not working.

After 6.0 i use paste keycode. All work.

So is paste shortcut was changed in 6.0? 
What is paste shortcut in android 6.0?

Comment: you are tolking about  emulator??   or your custom Keybord

Comment: I am talking about emulator/real device. I need to paste text in UiAutomator.I send KeyEvents to do paste action. uiObject.setText() does not fit.